# IRDOSession.GetFolderFromPath throws MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER error while Reading public folders through Redemption.dll

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption, tivoli-work-scheduler

I am upgrading one Console Application which is Read Outlook Public Folder.
It's working fine when I run manually. But throws exception when run through IBM Tivoli Workload Scheduler.

So tried to give inbox folder name instead of public folder name. Then it's working fine in Scheduler also. So only I get below error while try to read public folder alone

> Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER ulVersion:
>   0 Error: The attempt to log on to Microsoft Exchange has failed.
>   Component: Microsoft Exchange Information Store ulLowLevelError: 1144
>   ulContext: 1298

```
var session = new RDOSession();
session.Logon(string.Empty, string.Empty, false, true, null, null);
session.Stores.FindExchangePublicFoldersStore();
var publicFolder = session.GetFolderFromPath(folderPath);
```

Public folder:

> > \\Public Folders - example@domain.com\All Public Folders\XXX
> >     Folders\YYY/Object & Data\ZZZ\
>
> - Not working

Inbox folder:

> > \\example@domain.com\Inbox
>
> - Working

Edit: Added log and find out Exchange connection mode changing

> Manual Run ExchangeConnectionMode: `olCachedConnectedFull`
>
> Scheduler Run ExchangeConnectionMode: `olOnline`

**Note**: We are using **Redemption.dll - 5.10**

**Update:**
Old server Using Redemption.dll - 5.2 and Outlook 2003 with Exchange Server 2010. It's working fine with TWS also.
New server Using Redemption.dll - 5.10 and Outlook 2016 with Exchange Server 2010. But doesn't work with TWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue fix we need to do two things:

1. Click **Interactive**  options in TWS Jobs
2. Purchase Distributable version of **latest Redemption.dll** and use it

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the Public Folder store is not cached, so when you log under a service (scheduler), the store provider does not have the credentials to open the store.

Comment: I am also changed Exchange to Cached mode but still doesn't working

Comment: While running from scheduler ExchangeConnectionMode changing maybe it will help @Dmitry

Comment: Even if you enable the cached mode, it only applies to the primary mailbox, You can enable caching for the PF store Favorites, not for the whole PF store.

Comment: I don't think there is a good solution - apparently credentials manager does not or cannot see the credentials saved when Outlook was launched as an interactive user.

Comment: @Dimtry We are using 5.10 Redemption.dll is there anything to do with current issue also I am updated question with version details

Comment: I don't think this is Redemption version specific, the question is really when the PF store provider errors out.